# Socket.io socket.disconnect();

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Does anyone know where I should put the socket.disconnect function? My server code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

}
```

If I put the socket.disconnect(); function inside, it disconnects immediately. Does anyone know how to handle it?

EDIT:
I do not want to use socket.on('disconnect', function(){});

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  There is generally no reason to call `socket.disconnect()` from the server unless you're trying to kick a user off your server for some misbehavior reason or auth failure.

Comment: You may want to call `socket.disconnect()` in response to some event like `socket.on('disconnectMe', function() { socket.disconnect() } );` - just guessing ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're lost. You have 2 options:

- Using `socket.disconnect()` which will indeed disconnect the connection instantly.
- Using `socket.on('disconnect')` which will be triggered on a disconnect.

If you want to perform a specific action if the users disconnects, use the second one. If you want to force the user to disconnect for some reason, use the first one. Else, don't use any one of them.

Comment: You stated that the code on the top is server code. Now you are talking about closing a tab (which is client side). If you close the tab, it will disconnect anyhow and server will see this and you can perform an action on the server with socket.on('disconnect'). Waste of time helping someone like you.